# ASP Repeater, split into columns?

Tags: asp.net, css

Im working on a website written in .net which I have no idea how it works, I have the following code..

```
<ul id="mega"><li><a href="#">Products</a><div> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="RT_Category" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h2><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category")%></h2>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RT_SubCategory" runat="server" 
                DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubCat") %>'>
                <HeaderTemplate><p></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LinkS") %>'>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubcatName")%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></p></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div></li></ul>
```

This code outputs a list of product categories, my problem is that it lists them in 1 huge list however, Is it possible to somehow wrap a  around every 5 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article may help:

[Paging with Repeater control in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Aspnet_Repeater_Control.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You could try with CSS, `inline-block` or `float: left`

```
<ul id="mega"><li><a href="#">Products</a><div> 
    <asp:Repeater ID="RT_Category" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <div style="display: inline-block; width: 25%">
            <h2><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category")%></h2>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RT_SubCategory" runat="server" 
                DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubCat") %>'>
                <HeaderTemplate><p></HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LinkS") %>'>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SubcatName")%></a>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate></p></FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
          </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have seen examples of getting this to work with a `Repeater`, none are pretty. I suggest looking at the `DataList`, which has inbuilt properties to control repeating/columns.

[DataList.RepeatColumns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Akram's answer is apt for your case. However the repeater does look that nice. I would recommend using datalist for the same as it is more customizable, to output the data even column wise. Kindly refer this link: [Showing Multiple Records per Row with the DataList Control](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/showing-multiple-records-per-row-with-the-datalist-control-vb)